# Roblox puts an icon in my Mac dock without my permission

Tags: macos, permissions, dock

I have a Mac with OS X El Capitan. My daughter plays Roblox on my computer. Whenever she opens Roblox, a Roblox Studio icon is placed permanently on my dock. I have to manually drag it from the dock to remove it. I emailed Roblox about it and they said it was my computer and closed my ticket. They then asked me by email if I was satisfied or not! You can guess my answer. Neither Roblox nor Roblox Studio have Preferences or any other menu items when running. How can I stop this rude behavior on the part of Roblox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurred to me I could try deleting Roblox Studio--this seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: Alternatively you could set up a limited account for your daughter and swap between the two as required.

Answer (score 0):

Don't, delete roblox studio it will make it so you can't make games. I suggest you try to make an account for your daughter and for you.